# How can I create a data frame, like a 3D array with strings as indices?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

Basically what I am looking for is something which resembles panel variables in Python.

Ex : suppose the name of the data frame/array is `ARRAY`, then we can denote the values like this:

```
ARRAY['quick']['brown']['fox'] = 50; 

ARRAY['stack']['over']['flow'] = 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

stuctures: (struct)

```
array.quick.brown.fox = 50
array.stack.over.flow = 60
```

Comment: don't forget to add the syntax for use with strings or variables: e.g. `array.('quick')`

Comment: btw, not all strings are valid variable names: http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html#btcg64n